# How to changes the items in a combobox based on the selected value of another combobox in C#

Tags: c#, combobox

Once again I am in need of your assistance. I have two combobox's one called cmbRFR and one called cmbSubRFR. The items in the cmbRFR are:

- Null
- POSITIONING
- ARTEFACT
- PATIENT ID
- EXPOSURE ERROR
- TEST IMAGES

I need to set it up so that when the user selects one of the items in cmbRFR, it changes the items displayed in cmbSubRFR. cmbSubRFR should work as follows.

When user selects Null, the combobox should also display Null/a blank item.

When user selects POSITIONING:

- Anatomy cut-off
- Rotation
- Obstructed view
- Tube or grid centering
- Motion

When user selects ARTEFACT the combobox should also display ARTEFACT.

When user select PATIENT ID:

- Incorrect Patient
- Incorrect Study/Side
- User Defined Error

When user select EXPOSURE ERROR:

- Under Exposure
- Over Exposure
- Exposure Malfunction

When user selects TEST IMAGES:

- Quality Control
- Service/Test

I have no code to provide for this one as I have no idea how to go about doing this. I have looked around at some other questions that are similar to this however I have found nothing that might help me.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: look at selectedindexchange event on combobox.

Comment: How are these keyed to each other. For example can you select from a table where something = Patient ID and get the 3 results? Another method that may work is to build an object that holds the RFR name and holds a list of subRFR then when you select that object, you can get the list it contains and clear and populate the subRFR combobox.

Comment: intercept the OnSelectedIndexChange of cmbRFR, and fill the cmbSubRFR items accordingly based on SelectedItem property of cmbRFR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string cmbRFR_item;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void change_cmbSubRFR_items()
    {
        cmbSubRFR.Items.Clear();//Clear all items in cmbSubRFR comboBox.
        switch (cmbRFR_item)//Adding your new items to cmbSubRFR.
        {
            case "Null":
                cmbSubRFR.Items.Add("Null/a blank item");
                cmbSubRFR.Text = "Null/a blank item";
                break;
            case "POSITIONING":
                cmbSubRFR.Items.Add("Anatomy cut-off");
                cmbSubRFR.Items.Add("Rotation");
                cmbSubRFR.Items.Add("Obstructed view");
                cmbSubRFR.Items.Add("Tube or grid centering");
                cmbSubRFR.Items.Add("Motion");
                cmbSubRFR.Text = "";
                break;
            case "ARTEFACT":
                cmbSubRFR.Items.Add("ARTEFACT");
                cmbSubRFR.Text = "ARTEFACT";
                break;
            case "PATIENT ID":
                cmbSubRFR.Items.Add("Incorrect Patient");
                cmbSubRFR.Items.Add("Incorrect Study/Side");
                cmbSubRFR.Items.Add("User Defined Error");
                cmbSubRFR.Text = "";
                break;
            case "EXPOSURE ERROR":
                cmbSubRFR.Items.Add("Under Exposure");
                cmbSubRFR.Items.Add("Over Exposure");
                cmbSubRFR.Items.Add("Exposure Malfunction");
                cmbSubRFR.Text = "";
                break;
            case "TEST IMAGES":
                cmbSubRFR.Items.Add("Quality Control");
                cmbSubRFR.Items.Add("Service/Test");
                cmbSubRFR.Text = "";
                break;
        }
    }
    private void cmbRFR_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        if (cmbRFR_item!= cmbRFR.SelectedItem.ToString())//This will control your changes in cmbRFR about selected item and call change_cmbSubRFR_items()
        {
            cmbRFR_item = cmbRFR.SelectedItem.ToString();
            change_cmbSubRFR_items();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps provide some context, explaining why the code you posted should work. That way your answer will be much more informative.

Comment: This doesn't seem like it would work. It's adding items to one combo box. So if they select one specific item on the first combo box, then select a different item, its going to keep adding items.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go about solving this. First the "correct way", which is to set the [DataSource property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8160f6f(v=vs.110).aspx). Create lists for each combobox, like this:

```
var _positioningItems = new List<string> { "Anatomy cut-off", "Rotation", "Obstructed view" };
var _patientIdItems = new List<string> { "Incorrect Patient", "Incorrect Study/Side", "User Defined Error" };
```

Then subscribe to the `OnSelectedIndexChange` event on the `cmbRFR` combobox and then in the event handler, set the DataSource to the appropriate list.

The other way to do it, which I'm not in favor of, is to create comboboxes for each `cmbRFR` item, then hide them all and only show the appropriate one to the user. Subscribe to the `OnSelectedIndexChange` event on the `cmbRFR` combobox and hide/show the appropriate combobox.

Comment: Hello, sorry to be a noob about this but where do I put the variables and how do I subscribe to the index change, I've never had to do it before.

Comment: @iiAaronXiX - put the variables in your class and to subscribe to an event, go into designer view and click on the combo box. Then on the properties window, look for an icon that looks like a lightning bolt. This is the events page. click that and scroll down and find "SelectedIndexChanged". Double click it and thats it!